# WinForms C# Picturebox in source

Tags: c#, winforms, output, picturebox

How do I put a Picturebox in the Form with using the source code (no Designer)?
I've tried this:

```
  PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
  pb.Size = new Size(10,10);
  pb.Location = new Point(10,10);
  pb.ImageLocation= @"C:\Users\user\Desktop\NoName\NoName\StandardPos.png";
  pb.Load();
  pb.Refresh();
  pb.Show();
```

but there is something I'm missing.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/319266 Top result on Google "C# programatically add control to form"...

Answer (score 5):

You haven't added the box to the form:

```
        PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
        pb.Size = new Size(100, 100);
        pb.Location = new Point(100, 100);
        pb.ImageLocation = @"C:\Users\user\Desktop\NoName\NoName\StandardPos.png";
        this.Controls.Add(pb);  //< add it to the form
```

Answer (score 0):

this instruction:

pb.Parent=this ;

*And perhaps pb.BringToFront() instead of Refresh and Show().*